# Abrir pagina com informações

Tags: react-native

Tenho um FlatList e quero levar as informações que estão em um click pra abrir outra página.
Como na imagem em cada item do flat coloquei um `TouchableOpacity` e tem uma ação de click, quero abrir uma página com a informação que está nesse flat clicado.

[image: flatlist exibida no celular]

Comment: Olá, já tentou o react-navigation?

Answer (score 0):

- Instale o react-navigation: [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)
- Configure as rotas com o **stackNavigator**
- Chame a rota no onPress do item

  `<TouchableOppacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Details', {
     itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  })} >`
- Na tela em que está recebendo a rota, pegue esses parâmetros:
  `const itemId = this.navigation.getParam('itemId')`

Comment: Quanto a rota ou redirecionamento ta de boas, eu quero é levar a informação da lista clicada

Comment: @lyestah editei para ficar mais claro, qualquer coisa comente!

Answer (score 0):

Existem varias formas de fazer isso, todas elas você vai precisa do StackNavigation 2V ... e pra fazer a transição de uma tela pra outra basta criar um arquivo pra configurando as rotas usando o createStackNavigator ... e ao inves da sua toda apontar para esta pg ela vai apontar para o seu script de rota, dai lá vc vai configurar pra essa tela ser a primeira a ser carregada, depois é só decidir o que vc quer enviar para a tela de detalhes, se vc tem uma base local, sugiro enviar apenas o ID do objeto usando this.props.navigation.navigate(,idDoItemClicado) ... dai na outra pg vc usando o componentDidMount() pra poder fazer uma query ao montar o componente e carregar os dados que deseja utilizando o id.